# handleDelete function not working in React Firebase app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can someone help me figure out why my handleDelete function is not working? I tried passing the id from the button into the handlDelete function but it's still not working. Here is the handleDelete function:

```
//function for deleting an item
    const handleDelete = async (id) => {
        const taskDocRef = doc(db, 'tasks', id)
        console.log(taskDocRef);
        try {
            await deleteDoc(taskDocRef)
            console.log('task deleted');
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    }
```

Here is the return function:

```
return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h1>To Do List App</h1>re
                    <p>Double click to mark an item off, click on "X" to delete an item, and drag items to reorder.</p>
                </div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <button
                    type="submit"
                    onClick={handleAdd}
                >
                    Add
                </button>
            </div>

            <ol>
                {tasks.map((task => (
                    <li
                        id={task.data.id}
                        key={task.data.id}
                        completed={task.data.completed}
                        onClick={handleClick}
                    >
                        {task.data.name} <button onClick={() => handleDelete(task.data.id)}>x</button>
                    </li>
                )))}
            </ol>

        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: How are you generating the document ids?

Comment: Why u assume `handleDelete()` function not working. Tell me what is wrong with this line of code? `tasks.map((task => (...)))`

Comment: @SubramonianInian I am generating the ID's with this function:

const handleAdd = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            await addDoc(collection(db, 'tasks'), {
                name: name,
                id: uuidv4(),
                completed: false,
                created: Timestamp.now(),
            })
        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    }

Comment: @Mises What is wrong with that line of code? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @Julian Well you should learn JavaScript first if you don't know what is wrong with `.map()` method you try to use. Stop learning frameworks if you don't know the basics of language.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I had to update the useEffect function to include id: doc.id:

```
//function for automatically retrieving items
useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, 'tasks'), orderBy('created'))
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
        setTasks(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            id: doc.id,
            data: doc.data()
        })))
    })
    console.log(tasks);
}, [])
```

And the tasks.map function by changing task.data.id to task.id:

```
{tasks.map((task) => (
                <li
                    id={task.id}
                    key={task.id}
                    completed={task.data.completed}
                    onClick={handleClick}
                >
                    {task.data.name} <button onClick={() => handleDelete(task.id)}>x</button>
                </li>
            ))}
```